# What would be the correct way to use Exec or Transcode ffmpeg in SRS version of Windows 5.0.128

Tags: ffmpeg, srs, simple-realtime-server

i was doing tests in different ways, and i can't use the Exec or Transcode option, i highlight that I have copied the ffmpeg.exe in the objs folder.
These are the codes I tried, and I attach the log errors.

```
exec {

enabled on;

publish ./objs/ffmpeg.exe -rtbufsize 10M -i rtmp://10.1.9.240/live/encoder  -vf scale=1080:720 -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -level 4.2 -preset fast -b:v 1500k -c:a aac -ac 2 -b:a 96k -f flv -y rtmp://10.1.9.240:1935/live/encoderlow/;

}
```

**LOGS**

**[2023-01-04 10:05:46.410][WARN][1309][01568ctu][11] EXEC: Ignore error, code=3028(FFmpegFork)(Failed to fork FFmpeg trancoder process) :
process start : vfork process failed, cli=./objs/ffmpeg.exe -rtbufsize 10M -i rtmp://10.1.9.240/live/encoder -vf scale=1080:720 -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -level 4.2 -preset fast -b:v 1500k -c:a aac -ac 2 -b:a 96k -f flv -y rtmp://10.1.9.240:1935/live/encoderlow/
thread [1309][01568ctu]: do_cycle() [./src/app/srs_app_ng_exec.cpp:108][errno=11]
thread [1309][01568ctu]: start() [./src/app/srs_app_process.cpp:197][errno=11]**

transcode {

```
    enabled     on;

    ffmpeg      ./objs/ffmpeg.exe;

    engine ff {

        enabled         on;

        vfilter {

        }

        vcodec          libx264;

        vthreads        4;

        vprofile        high;

        vpreset         fast;

        vbitrate        1500k;

        vparams {

        }

        acodec          libfdk_aac;

        aparams {

        }

        output          rtmp://127.0.0.1:[port]/[app]/[stream]_[engine]?vhost=[vhost];

    }

}
```

**LOGS**

**[2023-01-04 11:04:45.295][WARN][1489][34r32764][11] Encoder: Ignore error, code=3028(FFmpegFork)(Failed to fork FFmpeg trancoder process) : ffmpeg start : vfork process failed, cli=./objs/ffmpeg.exe -f flv -i rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live?vhost=**defaultVhost**/encoder -vcodec libx264 -b:v 1500000 -threads 4 -profile:v high -preset fast -acodec libfdk_aac -f flv -y rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/encoder_ff?vhost=**defaultVhost** 1 > ./objs/ffmpeg-encoder-**defaultVhost**-live-encoder-ff.log 2 > ./objs/ffmpeg-encoder-**defaultVhost**-live-encoder-ff.log
thread [1489][34r32764]: do_cycle() [./src/app/srs_app_encoder.cpp:117][errno=11]
thread [1489][34r32764]: start() [./src/app/srs_app_process.cpp:197][errno=11]**

Answer (score 0):

SRS windows use cygwin64, which is not support fork `ffmpeg.exe` process on win32, so it does not work for neither exec or transcode.

So you can try win64, which should work well with `ffmpeg.exe`.

However, there is a workaround, to start a `ffmpeg.exe` process to do transcode manually, for example:

```bash
./objs/ffmpeg.exe -f flv -i rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/encoder \
  -vcodec libx264 -b:v 1500000 -threads 4 -profile:v high \
  -preset fast -acodec libfdk_aac -f flv \
  -y rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/encoder_ff
```

Because SRS will do this for you, but it's not a good idea to let SRS to do this. Instead, you should use HTTP callback to hook the on_publish event, then start a FFmpeg process. Like this:

```
Client(OBS as such) --RTMP--> SRS ---HTTP-callback--> Go server
                               ^                          |
                               |                          V
                               ^--RTMP-- FFmpeg <--fork---+
```

> Note: You should write a Go(or Nodejs or Python) server, for SRS to send HTTP request to, with the stream information, then fork new FFmpeg process to transcode RTMP stream, see [HTTP Callback](https://ossrs.io/lts/en-us/docs/v5/doc/http-callback)

The reason is quiet straight forward: To start and manage FFmpeg processes, we should use Go/Nodejs/Python backend server, but not C/C++ server like SRS or Nginx.

> PS: Please remove the last slash of `rtmp://10.1.9.240:1935/live/encoderlow/` to `rtmp://10.1.9.240:1935/live/encoderlow` because they are not the same URL for RTMP.